# PDF/X-3 file format info string

Tags: pdf

The PDF/X-3 file format requires an `info string` to be saved (see for example export via [Scribus](http://scribus.net)). What should it contain? Who is going to see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty arbitrary, actually. Doesn't make a scrap of difference what you put in it, because the cases in which it's used are almost non-existent.

For comparison, InDesign's output dialog has an Output Intent Profile Name (which you need -- that's the target color profile), an Output Condition Name that's blank by default and that no-one (and I've enquired quite deeply) ever uses, an Output Condition Identifier that is fixed as "CGATS TR 001" and Registry Name that is also fixed at "http://www.color.org".